# Tightening constraints for better formulation

Tags: mixed-integer-programming

Lately, I have been reading a lot of papers where the constraints have been tightened to include better formulations leading to decrease in optimiality gaps and also the time for solving the optimisation problem. I was wondering if there is a book or paper which folks would be aware about introducing constraint tightening in MIPs? I don't imagine it to be hit and trial approach, there definitely seems to be some good theory behind it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cutting plan algorithm is really a strange method to solve integer programming. In some cases, it works very well, and in some cases, it works vice versa. I think besides the theoretical overview of this method many trials and errors should be applied to understand how it works well on a specific problem. In this case, some resources that might be useful are:

- [Integer Programming: Laurence Wolsey](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781119606475)
- [Algorithm for simplifying a set of linear inequalities](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5359/algorithm-for-simplifying-a-set-of-linear-inequalities)
- [Valid Inequalities and Strong Inequalities](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1476/valid-inequalities-and-strong-inequalities)
- [Valid Inequality Verification for MIP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203194/valid-inequality-verification-for-mip)
- [Converting Weak to Strong MIP Formulations (Gurobi webinar)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4h4ZUlUpR8)
- [Performance of a branch and bound algorithm VS branch-cut-heuristics](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/performance-of-a-branch-and-bound-algorithm-vs-branch-cut-heuristics)
- [Learning to Select Cuts for Efficient Mixed-Integer Programming](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.13645.pdf)
- [Tobias Achtenberg PhD thesis](https://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-zib/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/1112/file/Achterberg_Constraint_Integer_Programming.pdf)
- [Cutting Plane Separators in SCIP](https://www.scipopt.org/download/slides/SCIP-cuttingPlanes.pdf)

Comment: My apologies for the late response. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Ishaan, your welcome. 